# HTML and CSS p selector wont work without h1 selector

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new to HTML and CSS and I encountered a strange issue. I am trying to change the color of my text with style and p selector and it works as long as I use h1 selector as well. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Indicates which HTML version is being used  -->
<html>  <!-- HTML starts here  --> <!-- Also called root element -->
    <head>  <!-- background/setup information goes inside head -->
        <meta charset = "utf-8" /> <!-- defines character set -->
        <title> Hello Internet! </title> <!-- website title name -->

        <style type = "text/css"> <!-- Added for CSS -->


            h1{

            }


            p{
            color: red;
            }

        </style>

</head>

<body>


<p> This text is red   </p>



</html>
```

So with this code my line of text is actually red but as soon as I remove the h1 selector from the code, the text goes back to black. Can anyone explain please why this is happening ?

Comment: Unrelated but don't forget to close your `<body>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put an HTML comment in there! Remove the comment and it will work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Indicates which HTML version is being used  -->
<html>
<!-- HTML starts here  -->
<!-- Also called root element -->

<head>
    <!-- background/setup information goes inside head -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- defines character set -->
    <title> Hello Internet! </title>
    <!-- website title name -->
    <style type="text/css">
    p {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p> This text is red </p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to add comments to the `<style>` tag, use CSS comments:

```
/**
 * This is a valid CSS comment
 */
/* This one too! */
/***************************
****************************
Even this one!
****************************
***************************/
```

Comment: huh, it worked. Ok, this is stupid. Why does the comment have any effect on my code ? I mainly code in C++ and Java and I expected the comment to have 0 effect on the actual code.

Comment: The `<style>` tag expects CSS syntax, and an HTML comment like `<!-- This -->` uses, among other things, valid CSS selectors like `>`, which breaks the flow of the CSS code.

Comment: Ooh I get it now. I was using HTML style comment in CSS part of the code huh. Cool, thank you very much my friend.

Comment: Unrelated question :) My Notepad++ wont color CSS comments(They are just black). Is there an easy way to fix this ?

Comment: Here's your answer to that question: http://superuser.com/questions/235320/different-language-syntax-highlighting-within-same-file

Comment: Just use Sublime Text I'd say.

Comment: I kind of grew to love Notepad ++ so I really do not want to switch editors.

Answer (score 2):

The comment you have inside your  tag is breaking your CSS. CSS uses different style comments.  Either the delete the comment or move it up outside the  tag.  Additionally, you are missing a closing  tag. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you tried to comment out (Notes in your code) your CSS using html styled. In order to comment things out of your code - or remove them from being processed- you have to type different things depending on the code language.

in HTML you comment words out like this:

```
 <!-- This is a comment -->
```

In CSS you comment words out like this: `/*comment*/`